# Upload to Azure Blob from Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-storage

I'm trying to upload an image's stream to Azure Blob from a Xamarin.Forms PCL app using WindowsAzure.Storage 7.0.2-preview. For some reason, the StorageCredentials doesn't recognize the AccountName of the SAS token.

```
var credentials = new StorageCredentials("https://<ACCOUNT-NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/...");
CloudStorageAccount Account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
```

And then uploading it like this:

```
 public async Task<string> WriteFile(string containerName, string fileName, System.IO.Stream stream, string contentType = "")
    {
        var container = GetBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var fileBase = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        await fileBase.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
        {
            fileBase.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
            await fileBase.SetPropertiesAsync();
        }
        return fileBase.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

How can I resolve my problem? Is there a better solution of uploading to Azure Storage?
Thank you!

Comment: what *specific* error or exception are  you getting?

Comment: @Jason The error is: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: AccountName

Comment: have you tried just using your Account name, and not a url?

Comment: @Jason Yes, it throws me the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StorageCredentials constructor that takes in a SAS token expects just the query part of the SAS token, not the full URI string.  If you have the full URI to a resource, including the SAS token, the most common thing to do is to use the constructor for that object directly.  For example, if you have the URI:

```
string myBlobUri = @"https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sascontainer/sasblob.txt?sv=2015-04-05&st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&spr=https&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D";
```

you can just create a blob object as such:

```
CloudBlockBlob fileBase = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(myBlobUri));
```

If you do want to use the StorageCredentials and CloudStorageAccount classes for some reason (maybe you have an AccountSAS, for example), here is one way to make that work:

```
string sasToken = @"sv=2015-04-05&st=2015-04-29T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2015-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&spr=https&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D";
StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(sasToken);
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, "myaccount", "core.windows.net", true)
```